# Encountering "Unsupported class file major version 65" Error in Gradle Initialization Script on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gradle, build.gradle

I'm facing an issue with my Android project in Visual Studio Code. The error message is "Unsupported class file major version 65," and it points to the Gradle initialization script. I've tried updating Java and Gradle, but the problem persists. How can I resolve this issue and successfully build my project?

The error I got;

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Erman/Desktop/MainFiles/AppCode/universal_web/android/",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The supplied phased action failed with an exception.\r\nCould not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\\Users\\Erman\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\redhat.java\\1.25.1\\config_win\\org.eclipse.osgi\\55\\0\\.cp\\gradle\\init\\init.gradle' (C:\\Users\\Erman\\.gradle\\caches\\8.1.1\\scripts\\2bo8rpvqtpmxrmn9s4y0rkz2x).\r\nBUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65\r\nUnsupported class file major version 65",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

I updated the gradle version to 8.5 but I was still getting the same problem. Afterwards, I updated the Java version, but I continued to get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Need to downgrade `logback-core`

In the root project `build.gradle`
add `logback-core` classpath to force a version

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    // your plugins
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.14")
        // rest of classpath
    }
       
}
```

The rest of the error I was facing was

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file /Users/<username>/.gradle/caches/jars-9/logback-core-1.5.0.jar.
```

so some issue with `1.5.0` (complied with newer java version)